# Can Somebody help me to optimize this test class. I want limit this test class to 100-150 lines

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

```
@isTest
  private class Verification_Callcenter_Test{
   static Verification__c verobj = null;
    public static void CreateFirstCommonVerificationData() {    
      verobj = new Verification__c(Status__c = 'Unverified Hit', Contact_State__c ='BH' , Applicant_Name__c ='test name emp', Type__c = 'Reference Verification', Action_Log__c = 'test', Action_Log_Notes__c = 1, Reviewed_By_Admin__c = true, Length_of_acquaintance_New__c = 'test', Ref_Relationship__c = 'test');
      insert verobj;
    }
    public static void CreateSecondCommonVerificationData() {    
        verobj = new Verification__c(Status__c = 'Pending', Contact_State__c ='BH', School__c = 'test school', 
        Internal_Notes__c = 'test note', Automated_System__c = true, TriggerControl_Result__c = 'Ans TWN', HoldHour__c = 2,
        HoldMonth__c = 3, HoldYear__c = 2012 , HoldDay__c = 2, Contact_Fax__c = '1234567890', Contact_Email__c = 'om@arcscorp.net', Action_Log__c = 'test', Action_Log_Notes__c = 1);
        insert verobj;
    }
    public static void CreateCommonAttachmentData() {
      Associated_Email__c oEmail = new Associated_Email__c(Assign_To_Verification__c = null, From_Address__c = 'om@arcscorp.net', To_Address__c = 'om@arcscorp.net'  );
      insert oEmail;
      Attachment oattach = new Attachment(name = 'test', body = Blob.valueOf('Hello'));
      oattach.ParentId = oEmail.Id;
      insert oattach;
    }
    public static void CreateCommonSecondAttachmentData() {
      account acc1= new account(Name = 'testing');
      insert acc1;
      People_Controller__c OPController1 = new People_Controller__c(Account__c =  acc1.id, Drug_Test_Completed__c = true, Drug_Test_Requested__c =true );
      insert OPController1;
      BGC_Order__c oBGCOrder1 = new BGC_Order__c (Joe_s_Account__c =acc1.id,Account__c = acc1.id, Subject_Address__c = 'abc', Subject_City__c = 'test', Subject_Zip_Code__c = '12345', Government_ID_Number__c = '123456789', Subject_Date_of_Birth__c = date.today(), Subject_First_Name__c = 'test', Subject_Last_Name__c = 'test', Government_ID_Type__c = 'other', Subject_Phone_Number__c = '0987654');
      insert oBGCOrder1;
      PreEmploy_Case__c  OPCase1 = new PreEmploy_Case__c(Account__c =acc1.id, Order_Number__c = oBGCOrder1.id);
      insert OPCase1;
      Background_Search__c oBSearch1 = new Background_Search__c(PreEmploy_Case__c =OPCase1.id, Account__c = acc1.id);
      insert oBSearch1;
      verobj = new Verification__c(Status__c = 'Unverified Hit', Contact_State__c ='BH' , Applicant_Name__c ='test name emp', Type__c = 'Employment Verification', PreEmploy_Case__c = OPCase1.id, Background_Search__c = oBSearch1.id, Sub_Stat__c = 'New Reference Provided', Action_Log__c = 'test', Action_Log_Notes__c = 1);
      insert verobj;
      Associated_Email__c oEmail = new Associated_Email__c(Assign_To_Verification__c = verobj.Id, From_Address__c = 'om@arcscorp.net', To_Address__c = 'om@arcscorp.net'  );
      insert oEmail;
      Associated_Email__c oEmail1 = new Associated_Email__c(Assign_To_Verification__c =null, From_Address__c = 'om@arcscorp.net', To_Address__c = 'om@arcscorp.net', Record_Locked__c = false, Archived__c = false);
      insert oEmail1;
      Attachment oattach = new Attachment(name = 'test', body = Blob.valueOf('Hello'));
      oattach.ParentId = oEmail.Id;
      insert oattach;
    }

    private static testmethod void testverification(){    
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateSecondCommonVerificationData();
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateCommonAttachmentData();
        System.currentPagereference().getParameters().put('id', verobj.id);
        Verification_Callcenter ver = new Verification_Callcenter();
        PageReference pr;
        pr = ver.autorun();
        pr = ver.invokeNotes();
        pr = ver.setReviewedByAdmin();
        pr = ver.setAutomatedSystem();
        pr = ver.SaveVerifierEmailApplicant('Email Applicant for - Clarification of dates');
        pr = ver.SaveVerifierEmailApplicant('Email Applicant for - Exhausted attempts Request');
        pr = ver.SaveVerifierEmailApplicant('Email Applicant for - No Record Found per Third Party Request Docs');
        pr = ver.SaveVerifierEmailApplicant('Email Applicant for - Request docs All years worked');
        pr = ver.SaveVerifierEmailApplicant('Email Applicant for - Request docs DNC');
        List<SelectOption> gd = ver.getddlActivityType();
        gd = ver.getddlAutomatedSystemUsed(); 
        gd = ver.getddlStatus();
        gd = ver.getItemsDropdown2();
        ver.FaxContact();
        ver.showEmailPopup();
        ver.toggleGN();
        ver.setThisStatus();
        ver.setThisType();
        ver.Sub_Stat = '';
        System.assert(pr == null );  
    }

    private static testmethod void testverification_2(){    
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateSecondCommonVerificationData();
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateCommonAttachmentData();
        System.currentPagereference().getParameters().put('id', verobj.id);
        Verification_Callcenter ver = new Verification_Callcenter();
        PageReference pr;
        pr = ver.autorun();
        pr = ver.invokeNotes();
        pr = ver.setReviewedByAdmin();
        pr = ver.setAutomatedSystem();
        pr = ver.SaveVerifierEmailApplicant('Email Applicant for - Clarification of dates');
        pr = ver.VerificationAdminReviewComplete();
        pr = ver.SaveCompleteAdminReview();
        pr = ver.SavePendingResponseEmail();
        ver.getItemEmail();
        List<SelectOption> gd = ver.getddlActivityType();
        gd = ver.getddlAutomatedSystemUsed(); 
        gd = ver.getddlStatus();
        gd = ver.getItemsDropdown2();
        ver.FaxContact();
        ver.showEmailPopup();
        ver.toggleGN();
        ver.setThisStatus();
        ver.setThisType();
        ver.Sub_Stat = '';
        System.assert(pr == null );  
    }

    private static testmethod void testverification7(){
      Account oAccount = new account(Name = 'IT Testing Account - 1');
      insert oAccount;
      Contact oContact = new Contact(LastName='ContTest1', Email='test1contact@duptest.com', AccountId = oAccount.Id);
      insert oContact;
      Profile p = [SELECT id, name FROM profile WHERE Name = '2014PE Customer Portal - Client'];
      User u = new User(alias = 'ccauto', email='amitstandarduser1@testorg.com',
      emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Test1', languagelocalekey='en_US',
      localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p.Id, Contactid = oContact.id,
      timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='amitstandarduser1@testorg.com');
      insert u; 
      System.runAs(u) {
        Verification_Action_Note__c VeriActionNote = new Verification_Action_Note__c(Name = 'Test Note', Type__c = 'Degree Verification', Finish_Status__c = 'Clear', Sub_Status_Name__c = 'Variance Acceptable - Verify');
        insert VeriActionNote;
        verification__c verobj5 = new Verification__c(Status__c = 'Pending', Contact_State__c ='BH', School__c = 'test school', Type__c = 'Degree Verification',
        Internal_Notes__c = 'test note', Automated_System__c = true, TriggerControl_Result__c = 'Ans TWN', HoldHour__c = 2,
        HoldMonth__c = 3, HoldYear__c = 2012 , HoldDay__c = 2, Contact_Fax__c = '1234567890', Contact_Email__c = 'om@arcscorp.net');
        insert verobj5;
        PageReference pr;
        System.currentPagereference().getParameters().put('id', verobj5.id);
        Verification_Callcenter ver = new Verification_Callcenter();
        ver.autorun();
        ver.loadnotes('Clear', 'Variance Acceptable - Verify');
        pr = ver.setThisStatus() ;
        pr = ver.setThisType();
        pr = ver.archiveEmail();
        pr = ver.emailVer();
        pr = ver.pullNextSearch();
        pr = ver.redirectorTrue();
        pr = ver.SaveComplete();
        ver.closePopup();  
        ver.setScript();
        ver.verAttachments();
        ver.getAttemptItem();
        ver.getClarification();
        ver.getReference();        
        ver.getRequestPriority();      
        ver.sApplicantFax = '4534545';
        ver.sNotesToRequestApplicantEmail = 'sdfdsf';
        ver.sIntNotesEmail = 'sdf';
        ver.saveRequestApplicantEmail();
        ver.getddlCompleteStatus();
        ver.getReferenceStates();
        ver.VerificationThirdParty();
        ver.SaveThirdPartyVenderdetails();
        ver.VerificationFile();
        ver.ApplicantClientProvidedDocuments = true;
        ver.invokeApplicantClientProvidedDocuments();
        ver.ApplicantExpressResult = true;
        ver.invokeApplicantExpressResult();
        ver.VerificationTypeMessage = 'asdas';
        ver.reSubmit = true;
        ver.sPersonContactNumber = 'asdas';
        ver.sPersonName = 'asdas';
        ver.sPersonPosition = 'asdas';
        ver.sApplicantPersonName = 'asdas';
        ver.sApplicantPersonPosition = 'asdas';
        ver.sVId='cgcf';
        ver.sVAccId = 'fgfg';
        ver.currentSiteUrl = 'sdfsdf';
        ver.ssn = 'asds';
        ver.Client_Email = 'sdfsd';
        ver.Start_Date = '01/01/1900';
        ver.Contact_State = 'sdfsdf';
        ver.Previous_Employer = 'sdf';
        ver.Contact_Address = 'sdf';
        ver.End_Date = '01/01/1900';
        ver.Contact_Phone = 'sdsd';
        ver.Contact_Fax = 'sdf';
        ver.Contact_City = 'sdf';
        ver.Contact_Zip = 'sdf';
        ver.Emp_Remarks_To_Client = 'asd';
        ver.Employment_Attendance = 'sdf';
        ver.Employment_Rehire = 'sdfs';
        ver.Verified_Start_Date = '01/01/1900';
        ver.Verified_End_Date = '01/01/1900';
        ver.Employment_Reason_For_Leaving = 'sdf';
        ver.Verified_Position = 'sdf';
        ver.License_Comments = 'sdf';
        ver.License_Date_Issued = '01/01/1900';            
        ver.License_Expire_Date = '01/01/1900';
        ver.Issued_By = 'sdf';
        ver.Issued_By_Address = 'sdf';
        ver.Issued_By_City = 'sdf';
        ver.Issued_By_Fax = 'sdf';
        ver.Issued_By_Phone = 'asd';
        ver.Issued_By_State = 'sdf';
        ver.License_Number = 'asd';
        ver.License_Description = 'sdf';
        ver.License_Type = 'sdf';
        ver.Lic_Issued_By_Zip = 'sdf';
        ver.Degree_Earned = 'sdf';
        ver.Degree_Award_Date = '01/01/1900';
        ver.School_End_Date = '01/01/1900';
        ver.Major_Minor = 'sdf';
        ver.Education_Remarks = 'sdf';
        ver.School = 'sdf';
        ver.IsPhysicalSigned = true;
        ver.sTcktNumber = 'sdf';
        ver.sTcktSummery = 'sdf';
        ver.sRequestPriority = 'sdg';
        ver.School_Start_Date = '01/01/1900';
        ver.Length_of_acquaintance = 'sdfsd';
        ver.Ref_Relationship = 'sdf';
        ver.Reference_Remarks = 'sdf';
        ver.Reference_Relationship_Question = 'sdf';
        ver.Reference_Professional_Desc = 'sdf';
        ver.Reference_Strengths_Desc = 'sdf';
        ver.Reference_Improve_Desc = 'sdfsd';
        ver.Reference_Add_Comments = 'sdf';
        ver.AKA = 'sdf';
        ver.Verified_School_Name = 'sdf';
        ver.Verified_Degree_Major = 'sdf';
        ver.Verified_EDU_Start_Date = '01/01/1900';
        ver.Verified_Degree_Minor = 'sdf';
        ver.Verified_EDU_End_Date = '01/01/1900';
        ver.Verified_Degree_Earned = 'sdfsd';
        ver.Verified_Lic_Type = 'sdf';
        ver.Verified_Lic_Exp = '01/01/1900';
        ver.Verified_Lic_Issued_By = 'sdf';
        ver.Verified_Lic_Number = 'sdf';
        ver.Verified_Lic_Date_Rec = '01/01/1900';
        ver.Verified_Degree_Award_Date = '01/01/1900';
        ver.Verified_Lic_Type = 'sdf';
        ver.fileID = 'sdf';
        ver.AttachmentLink = 'sdf';
        ver.callStartTime = '01/01/1900';
        ver.HoldDay = '1';
        ver.HoldHour = '2';
        ver.HoldYear = '1222';
        ver.Company_Code = 'sdf';
        ver.Verifier_Name = 'sdf';
        ver.Verifier_Title = 'sdf';
        ver.Contact_Phone2 = 'sdfsd';
        ver.ContactTitle = 'sdf';
        ver.Additional_Remarks = 'sdf';
        ver.Attendance_Only = 'sdf';
        ver.Notes_To_CC = 'sdfsd';
        ver.LastAction = 'sdf';
        ver.sCallAttempt = 'sdf';
        ver.sEmailAttempt = 'sdfsd';
        ver.sFaxAttempt = 'sdfsd';
        ver.sURLId = 'sdf';
        ver.sReferencePhone = 'sdf';
        ver.sReferenceName = 'sdf';
        ver.sIntNotesTo = 'sdf';
        ver.sNotesToPersonApplicant = 'sdf';
        ver.sNotesToPersonVerifier = 'sdf';
        ver.sAcquaintance = 'sdf';
        ver.sReferenceEmail = 'sdf';
        ver.sRelationship = 'sdf';
        ver.sReferenceStateId = 'sdf';
        ver.sCaseStatus = 'sdfsd';
        ver.sReason = 'sdf';
        ver.sPriority = 'sdf';
        ver.sAction = 'sdf';
        ver.isVerificationThirdParty = false;
      }
    }   

  private static testmethod void testverification1(){
      Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateFirstCommonVerificationData();
        System.currentPagereference().getParameters().put('id', verobj.id);
        Verification_Callcenter ver = new Verification_Callcenter();
        PageReference pr;
        pr = ver.autorun();
        ver.emailVerifications('test name emp');
        ver.searchVerifications('test name emp');
        ver.bpeVerifications('test name emp');
        ver.Client_Notes = 'testing';
        ver.save();
        System.assert(pr == null );  
   }
  private static testmethod void testverification2(){     
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateFirstCommonVerificationData();
        Attachment oattach = new Attachment(name = 'test', body = Blob.valueOf('Hello'));
        oattach.ParentId = verobj.Id;
        insert oattach;
        System.currentPagereference().getParameters().put('id', verobj.id);
        Verification_Callcenter ver = new Verification_Callcenter();
        PageReference pr;
        pr = ver.autorun();
        ver.getActionLogHistory();
        ver.getMyVerifications();
        ver.searchWord = 'searching';
        ver.searchVer();
        ver.getSearchReturnItems();
        ver.EmailContact('om@arcscorp.net', 'Test mail');
        ver.EmailApplicant('om@arcscorp.net', 'Test mail');
        ver.outgoingNumber = '1234567890';
        ver.logCall('1234567890', system.now());
        System.assert(pr == null  );  
   }
    private static testmethod void testverification3(){   
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateSecondCommonVerificationData();
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateCommonAttachmentData();
        account acc1= new account(Name = 'testing');
        insert acc1;
        System.currentPagereference().getParameters().put('id', verobj.id);
        Verification_Callcenter ver = new Verification_Callcenter();
        PageReference pr;
        URL__c ourl = new URL__c(Name = 'URL', Email__c = 'Test@Test.com', Internal__c = 'Test', Internal_Url__c = 'Test', MainProtal__c = 'Test', Mybackgroundcheck_Community__c = 'Test', MyBackgroundCheckResults_Portal__c = 'Test', SalesforceContent__c = 'Test', SidesDotNet__c = 'Test');
        insert ourl;
        pr = ver.autorun();
        ver.emailVerifications('test name emp');
        ver.searchVerifications('test name emp');
        ver.bpeVerifications('test name emp');
        ver.Client_Notes = 'testing';
        ver.save();
        ver.toggleSsn();
        ver.toggleBPE();
        ver.toggleDob();
        ver.getBPEReturnItems();
        String sTBW_Sent_Date = ver.TBW_Sent_Date;
        String sECC_Status = ver.ECC_Status;
        String sCall_Center_Notes = ver.Call_Center_Notes;
        String sLast_Update = ver.Last_Update;

        ver.SavePersonVerifier();
        ver.sfaxattachment = null;
        String ssfaxSelected = ver.sfaxSelected;
        ver.getFaxSRAttachment();
        String sNotesTBW = ver.sNotesTBW;
        ver.TBWReroute();
        ver.PendingAutomatedSystem();
        ver.ApprovalThirdParty();
        ver.OtherThirdParty();
        ver.SaveComplete(); 
        ver.SaveFaxConfirmed();
        ver.SaveApplicantFax();
        String sContact_Email = ver.Contact_Email;
        ver.InternalActionLog = 'gfgfdgfdg';
        System.assert(pr == null);  
   }

   private static testmethod void testverification31(){   
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateSecondCommonVerificationData();
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateCommonAttachmentData();
        account acc1= new account(Name = 'testing');
        insert acc1;
        System.currentPagereference().getParameters().put('id', verobj.id);
        Verification_Callcenter ver = new Verification_Callcenter();
        PageReference pr;
        URL__c ourl = new URL__c(Name = 'URL', Email__c = 'Test@Test.com', Internal__c = 'Test', Internal_Url__c = 'Test', MainProtal__c = 'Test', Mybackgroundcheck_Community__c = 'Test', MyBackgroundCheckResults_Portal__c = 'Test', SalesforceContent__c = 'Test', SidesDotNet__c = 'Test');
        insert ourl;
        pr = ver.autorun();
        ver.SaveVerifierFax();
        ver.SaveVerifier();
        ver.getRequestPriority();
        ver.SavePersonApplicant();
        ver.SaveApplicantReached();
        ver.SaveETA();
        ver.svalue = 'Manually Emailed Verifier';
        ver.sNotesToClientManuallyFax = 'test';
        ver.sInternalNoteManuallyFax = 'test';
        ver.sNotesToClientPendingResponseFax = 'test';
        ver.sInternalNotePendingResponseFax = 'test';
        ver.SaveManuallyFax();
        ver.SavePendingResponseFax();
        ver.SaveUnverifier();
        ver.SaveThirdPartyVenderdetails();
        ver.getItem();
        ver.emailVerifications('test');
        ver.save();
        ver.svalue = 'Manually Emailed Verifier';
        ver.sfaxattachment = 'test';
        pr = ver.Save_Email();
        pr = ver.SaveManuallyEmail();
        ver.svalue = 'Manually Sent Fax';
        pr = ver.Save_Fax();
        pr = ver.SaveManuallyFax();
        pr = ver.SaveVerifierEmail();
        ver.saveRequestApplicantEmail();
        //pr = ver.SaveApplicantEmail();
   }
    private static testmethod void testverification8(){
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateSecondCommonVerificationData();
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateCommonSecondAttachmentData();
        Verification_Callcenter ver = new Verification_Callcenter();
        PageReference pr;
        pr = ver.autorun();
        ver.archiveEmail();
        pr = ver.pullNextSearch();
        ver.loadVerification(verobj.Id);
        ver.save();
        ver.emailVerifications('test');
        ver.emailWord = 'test';
        ver.emailVer();
        ver.SaveComplete();
        ver.reSubmit = true;
        ver.SaveThirdPartyVenderdetails();
        ver.SaveRemoveAdminReview();    
        System.assert(pr == null);
   }
       private static testmethod void testverification18(){
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateSecondCommonVerificationData();
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateCommonSecondAttachmentData();
        Verification_Callcenter ver = new Verification_Callcenter();
        PageReference pr;
        pr = ver.autorun();
        ver.archiveEmail();
        pr = ver.pullNextSearch();
        ver.loadVerification(verobj.Id);
        ver.save();
        ver.emailVerifications('test');
        ver.emailWord = 'test';
        ver.emailVer();
        ver.SaveComplete();
        ver.reSubmit = true;
        ver.OtherThirdParty();
        ver.PendingAutomatedSystem();
        System.assert(pr == null);
   }
       private static testmethod void testverification118(){
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateSecondCommonVerificationData();
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateCommonSecondAttachmentData();
        Verification_Callcenter ver = new Verification_Callcenter();
        PageReference pr;
        pr = ver.autorun();
        ver.archiveEmail();
        pr = ver.pullNextSearch();
        ver.loadVerification(verobj.Id);
        ver.save();
        ver.emailVerifications('test');
        ver.emailWord = 'test';
        ver.emailVer();
        ver.SaveComplete();
        ver.reSubmit = true;
        ver.SavePendingResponseEmail();
        System.assert(pr == null);
   }
       private static testmethod void testverification1181(){
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateSecondCommonVerificationData();
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateCommonSecondAttachmentData();
        Verification_Callcenter ver = new Verification_Callcenter();
        PageReference pr;
        pr = ver.autorun();
        ver.archiveEmail();
        pr = ver.pullNextSearch();
        ver.SaveManuallyFax();
        ver.ApprovalThirdParty();
        ver.SaveCompleteAdminReview();  
        ver.TBWReroute();        
        System.assert(pr == null);
   }   
       private static testmethod void testverification188(){
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateSecondCommonVerificationData();
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateCommonSecondAttachmentData();
        Verification_Callcenter ver = new Verification_Callcenter();
        PageReference pr;
        pr = ver.autorun();
        ver.archiveEmail();
        pr = ver.pullNextSearch();
        ver.loadVerification(verobj.Id);
        ver.save();
        ver.emailVerifications('test');
        ver.emailWord = 'test';
        ver.emailVer();
        ver.SaveComplete();
        ver.reSubmit = true;
        ver.SaveApplicantEmail();
        System.assert(pr == null);
   } 
       private static testmethod void testverification198(){
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateSecondCommonVerificationData();
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateCommonSecondAttachmentData();
        Verification_Callcenter ver = new Verification_Callcenter();
        PageReference pr;
        pr = ver.autorun();
        ver.archiveEmail();
        pr = ver.pullNextSearch();
        ver.loadVerification(verobj.Id);
        ver.save();
        ver.emailVerifications('test');
        ver.emailWord = 'test';
        ver.emailVer();
        ver.SaveComplete();
        ver.reSubmit = true;
        ver.SavePendingResponseFax();
        ver.SaveFaxConfirmed();
        ver.SaveApplicantFax();
        System.assert(pr == null);
   }
       private static testmethod void testverification108(){
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateSecondCommonVerificationData();
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateCommonSecondAttachmentData();
        Verification_Callcenter ver = new Verification_Callcenter();
        PageReference pr;
        pr = ver.autorun();
        ver.archiveEmail();
        pr = ver.pullNextSearch();
        ver.loadVerification(verobj.Id);
        ver.save();
        ver.emailVerifications('test');
        ver.emailWord = 'test';
        ver.emailVer();
        ver.SaveComplete();
        ver.reSubmit = true;
        ver.SaveVerifierFax();
        ver.SaveUnverifier();
        ver.SaveETA();

        System.assert(pr == null);
   }
       private static testmethod void testverification100(){
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateSecondCommonVerificationData();
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateCommonSecondAttachmentData();
        Verification_Callcenter ver = new Verification_Callcenter();
        PageReference pr;
        pr = ver.autorun();
        ver.archiveEmail();
        pr = ver.pullNextSearch();
        ver.loadVerification(verobj.Id);
        ver.save();
        ver.emailVerifications('test');
        ver.emailWord = 'test';
        ver.emailVer();
        ver.SaveComplete();
        ver.reSubmit = true;
        ver.SaveApplicantReached();
        System.assert(pr == null);
   }
       private static testmethod void testverification101(){
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateSecondCommonVerificationData();
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateCommonSecondAttachmentData();
        Verification_Callcenter ver = new Verification_Callcenter();
        PageReference pr;
        pr = ver.autorun();
        ver.archiveEmail();
        pr = ver.pullNextSearch();
        ver.loadVerification(verobj.Id);
        ver.emailVerifications('test');
        ver.emailWord = 'test';
        ver.reSubmit = true;
        ver.SavePersonVerifier();
        ver.SaveVerifier();
        ver.processSearchLinkClick();

        System.assert(pr == null);
   }
       private static testmethod void testverification102(){
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateSecondCommonVerificationData();
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateCommonSecondAttachmentData();
        Verification_Callcenter ver = new Verification_Callcenter();
        PageReference pr;
        pr = ver.autorun();
        ver.archiveEmail();
        pr = ver.pullNextSearch();
        ver.loadVerification(verobj.Id);
        ver.save();
        ver.emailVerifications('test');
        ver.emailWord = 'test';
        ver.emailVer();
        ver.SaveComplete();
        ver.reSubmit = true;
        ver.SaveCreatedDevTckt();

        System.assert(pr == null);
   }
       private static testmethod void testverification103(){
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateSecondCommonVerificationData();
        Verification_Callcenter_Test.CreateCommonSecondAttachmentData();
        Verification_Callcenter ver = new Verification_Callcenter();
        PageReference pr;
        pr = ver.autorun();
        ver.archiveEmail();
        pr = ver.pullNextSearch();
        ver.loadVerification(verobj.Id);
        ver.save();
        ver.emailVerifications('test');
        ver.emailWord = 'test';
        ver.emailVer();
        ver.SaveComplete();
        ver.reSubmit = true;
        ver.saveRequestApplicantEmail();


        System.assert(pr == null);
   }


 }
```

Answer (score 2):

As well as reducing code duplication, you should also be thinking about doing more asserting of the behavior of the controller. Also, someone reading your test should be able to understand what the controller does much more than is possible with the current test code. But if it is any consolation, writing good tests for controllers is hard. Some tests have to be much longer than the code that is being tested.

A good starting point for more complicated tests is to apply the [builder pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/the-builder-pattern-for-test-classes) so that messy sequences of operations are given a name via the builder class method name e.g.:

```
public class VerBuilder {
    ...
    private Verification_Callcenter ver;
    ...
    public class MyBuilder defaultAllFields() {
        ver.VerificationTypeMessage = 'asdas';
        ver.reSubmit = true;
        ...
        return this;
    }
    ...
}
```

then individual tests can be much more succinct and execute different combinations of the building blocks:

```
new VerBuilder()
    .defaultAllFields();
    ...
```

Don't write the builder at the level of setting each individual field as that adds no value; instead, write methods for more substantial pieced of behavior. And while it doesn't fit a pure definition of a builder class, include asserts in the methods and add specific assert methods (or additional assert classes) to confirm the results.